# Laravel 5.2 Monolog to output in Chrome console

Tags: php, google-chrome, monolog, laravel-5

I'm trying to implement monolog so it outputs to chrome console.  So far I have this, but when I log a message it doesn't output anything.

Is there anything else that needs to be done to make this work that I've missed?

In the past in CakePHP or CodeIgniter I pulled in ChromePHP and output to the console by typing `ChromePhp::log();`, but it seems like Laravel has a much cleaner way of doing this using Monolog.

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace TNC\Providers;

use Log;
use Monolog\Handler\ChromePHPHandler;
use Monolog\Formatter\ChromePHPFormatter;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Log::listen(function () {

            $monolog = Log::getMonolog();

            if (env('APP_ENV') === 'local') {
                $monolog->pushHandler($chromeHandler = new ChromePHPHandler());
                $chromeHandler->setFormatter(new ChromePHPFormatter());
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**Route.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    Log::info('General information log');

    return view('foundation.score');
});
```

Comment: Did you install chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-logger/noaneddfkdjfnfdakjjmocngnfkfehhd ?

Comment: Hi @xAoc, thanks for the reply.  I do have it installed.

Comment: very strange, because I've tested in laravel 5.1 and 5.2 and all works fine. Did you try to remove env == local? Maybe your environment isn't local?

Comment: Hi @xAoc, thanks that was it.  I removed the if-statement and it worked.  Checking my .env I had it set to production.  Thanks for the help, stupid mistake, but totally worth the points.  Post your solution and I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in the environment variable because it isn't a `local`.
Just auto mistake or lack of attention :)

Answer (score 2):

## bootstrap/app.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Custom Monolog Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#configuration
|
*/

$app->configureMonologUsing(function($monolog) {
    if (app()->environment('local')) {
        $monolog->pushHandler($chromeHandler = new Monolog\Handler\ChromePHPHandler());
        $chromeHandler->setFormatter(new Monolog\Formatter\ChromePHPFormatter);
    }
});

// ...

return $app;
```

## app/Http/routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    Log::info('General information log');

    return view('welcome');
});
```

## Screenshot

[Chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHvWA.png)